# undefined is not an object evaluating NativeReactModules.startApp

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I just created new react-native app.

tried to build the app and printing "Hello, World" and it worked fine.

and then I installed react-native-navigation, and tried to use it, I registered one screen and `startTabBasedApp`.

the app is now showing me this error message:

[image: error message]

---

Environment:

- React Native Navigation version: 1.1.171
- React Native version: 0.46.4
- Platform: Android
- Device info (Simulator/Device?): Simulator

---

MainApplication.java:

```
package com.relay-modern;

import android.app.Application;

import com.facebook.react.ReactApplication;
import com.facebook.react.ReactNativeHost;
import com.facebook.react.ReactPackage;
import com.facebook.react.shell.MainReactPackage;
import com.facebook.soloader.SoLoader;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

public class MainApplication extends Application implements ReactApplication {

  private final ReactNativeHost mReactNativeHost = new ReactNativeHost(this) {
    @Override
    public boolean getUseDeveloperSupport() {
      return BuildConfig.DEBUG;
    }

    @Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage()
      );
    }
  };

  @Override
  public ReactNativeHost getReactNativeHost() {
    return mReactNativeHost;
  }

  @Override
  public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();
    SoLoader.init(this, /* native exopackage */ false);
  }
}
```

Comment: btw, I tried react-native v0.47

Comment: Did you followed the configuration for Android? https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android

Comment: Oh, I didn't see this, I am sorry, will try and tell you

Comment: I have same problem,Are you got solution?

Comment: Yes, I just followed the tutorial here:
https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `MainApplication` should extends from `NavigationApplication`.

Please follow the [configuration for Android](https://wix.github.io/react-native-navigation/#/installation-android)